# How can I use slicing in numpy arrays correctly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, heatmap, numpy-slicing

I have a piece of code that has to generate a gaussian distribution over a few pixels of an image based on a set of coordinates and a confidence.

```
import numpy as np
def gen_single_joint_heatmap(x, y, conf, img_size, sigma=0.6, eps=1e-6):
heatmap = np.zeros(img_size)  # Outside the gaussians all values should be zero

for center_x, center_y, confidence in zip(x, y, conf):  # center of the gaussians and confidences of the centers
    if confidence < eps:
        continue
    
    # The centers are scaled between 0 and 1, so multiply by width and height to obtain the real coordinates
    center_x *= img_size[0]
    center_y *= img_size[1]

    # creating a range in which the gaussian is computed
    start_x = max(0, int(center_x - 3 * sigma))
    end_x = min(img_size[0], int(center_x + 3 * sigma))  # sigma is set to 0.6

    start_y = max(0, int(center_y - 3 * sigma))
    end_y = min(img_size[1], int(center_y + 3 * sigma))

    x = np.arange(start_x, end_x, 1, dtype=np.float32)
    y = np.arange(start_y, end_y, 1, dtype=np.float32)
    
    # if the x and y are 0, then continue
    if not (len(x) and len(y)):
        continue

    y = y[:, None]
    
    # Compute the gaussian
    patch = np.exp(-(x - center_x) ** 2 + (y - center_y) ** 2 / 2 / sigma ** 2)
    patch *= confidence

    print('x_length', end_x - start_x, end_y - start_y)
    print(heatmap[start_y:end_y, start_x:end_x].shape)
    # save the patch if it's higher than values of the heatmap
    heatmap[start_y:end_y, start_x:end_x] = np.maximum(heatmap[start_y:end_y, start_x:end_x], patch)
return heatmap
```

To do so, I am using this code, and, for some reason, it does not work. The problem apparently lies in the last assignment. Unfortunately, I get this error: `operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,0) (3,3)`, but if I print the lengths (in `print('x_length', end_x - start_x, end_y - start_y)`), the output I get is `x_length 3 3`, while the shape of the heatmap is `(3, 0)`. Does anyone have any idea why I get this error?

EDIT:

The shapes of the arrays, as requested, are: 1920x1080 for the full `heatmap`, divided by an integer scaling factor, while `patch` is (usually) a 3x3 shaped array, but sometimes can be bigger due to integer rounding.
Regarding the problem mentioned by @hpaulj, I thought that could be the case, but for some reason end_x - start_x is 3, but the dimension is still 0
Here is the full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/samuel/Desktop/internship_implementation/main.py", line 238, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/samuel/Desktop/internship_implementation/main.py", line 190, in main
    dataset = dataset[0]
  File "/home/samuel/Desktop/internship_implementation/data/pc3dDataset.py", line 60, in __getitem__
    frames = full_preprocess(full_path, data, self.sample_number, self.image_padding, self.channels,
  File "/home/samuel/Desktop/internship_implementation/pipelines/preprocess.py", line 17, in full_preprocess
    data = generate_heatmap(data, image_padding, img_size, channels, scale_factor, epsilon, sigma)
  File "/home/samuel/Desktop/internship_implementation/pipelines/preprocessing/keypoints_heatmap_related.py", line 241, in generate_heatmap
    frames_heatmap[i] = gen_frame_heatmap(rearranged_skeletons[i], new_img_size, epsilon, sigma)
  File "/home/samuel/Desktop/internship_implementation/pipelines/preprocessing/keypoints_heatmap_related.py", line 222, in gen_frame_heatmap
    new_skeletons[channel] = gen_single_joint_heatmap(skeleton[i], skeleton[i + 1], skeleton[i + 2],
  File "/home/samuel/Desktop/internship_implementation/pipelines/preprocessing/keypoints_heatmap_related.py", line 213, in gen_single_joint_heatmap
    heatmap[start_y:end_y, start_x:end_x] = np.maximum(heatmap[start_y:end_y, start_x:end_x], patch)
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,0) (3,3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably because your x and y inputs are 1D arrays themselves, and thus their shapes are broadcasted to your 'patch' variable, which ends up being of 1D shape (len(x),).

For example:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(0, 10, 1)
y = np.arange(0, 10, 1)

center_x, center_y = 2, 2
sigma = 0.2

# Compute the gaussian
patch = np.exp(-(x - center_x) ** 2 + (y - center_y) ** 2 / 2 / sigma ** 2)

print(patch.shape) # outputs (10,)
```

You should convert your 1D arrays to 2D arrays by using [np.meshgrid](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html#numpy-meshgrid):

```
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(0, 10, 1)
y = np.arange(0, 10, 1)

x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y) # Here

center_x, center_y = 2, 2
sigma = 0.2

# Compute the gaussian
patch = np.exp(-(x - center_x) ** 2 + (y - center_y) ** 2 / 2 / sigma ** 2)

print(patch.shape) # Outputs (10, 10)
```

Comment: Ho, and your Gaussian function is off. It should be:

patch = np.exp(-((x - center_x) ** 2 + (y - center_y) ** 2) / (2 * sigma ** 2))

Comment: I saw a piece of code online that used `y = y[:, None]` to change y to a different shape and have a patch that  was 2-dimensional. By replacing that line of code with `np.meshgrid`, as you suggested, it worked out. Also, thank you for the correction on the gaussian function

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to see more information, array shapes, full traceback, etc, but my guess is that there problem lies in:

```
np.maximum(heatmap[start_y:end_y, start_x:end_x], patch)
```

and specifically

```
heatmap[start_y:end_y, start_x:end_x]
```

has shape (3,0).  That would because `start_x` is already at the end, and `start_x:end_x` "steps" off the end of the array, resulting in a size 0 dimension.

Comment: Edited the question adding the information you requested

Comment: in python, indexing off the end of a list or array gives an error, but slicing just gives 0 dimension. eg  `[1,2,3][4]` versus `[1,2,3][4:5]`